# Can a OneDrive folder with Office docs behave like a git repo?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, git, onedrive, github

I have a folder in OneDrive containing a Microsoft Word doc, an Excel spreadsheet, and some other less important files. I'd like to share this folder as a project to collaborate on with others, but I'd like our collaboration workflow to feel like collaborating on a project on GitHub.

- I maintain authority and approve any edits/additions made (pull request)
- Anyone can add comments (raise issues)

Is this possible?

---

I'm working on this now, and can post an answer to this eventually, but I'm hoping someone with more expertise than me can chime it. It looks like these settings have to be turned on in individual files though? *Track Changes* and *Restrict Access* inside the Word doc. Idk about the Excel file. If there are other features important to a git-like workflow, they should be added to this question text :)

Comment: Bonus question: how long do you think it'll be before Microsoft starts integrating GitHub and OneDrive into a single product? ;)

Comment: That probably won't ever happen.